# Adwords Exported CSV Report Parsing in PHP not working

Tags: php, file-permissions, fopen, fgetcsv

I have created a table which I am trying to populate with data from a CSV file exported from AdWords. Following is my table -

[image: Adwords Table]

The table is only displayed when ajax call is successful because the table HTML is returned by the page I make ajax request to. As you can see I'm getting the table columns and the table is being populated properly but I'm not getting the values for some reason.

**GENERATING TABLE WITH VALUES FROM FUNCTION**

```
        $campaigns_data = getCampaignsCSVData($account_name);           

        $campaigns_columns = $campaigns_data['columns'];                
        $campaigns_values = $campaigns_data['values'];                          


        if(!empty($campaigns_columns) && !empty($campaigns_values)){
            echo '<h4>Campaign Totals</h4>'.PHP_EOL;        
            getCampaignsTable($campaigns_columns,$campaigns_values,$campaigns_included_cols,'Clicks','DESC');
        }
```

**FUNCTION TO GENERATE CAMPAIGNS TABLE**

```
function getCampaignsTable($columns,$values,$included_cols,$sort_by='',$sort_dir='ASC'){

        $values_by_column_key = array();        

        foreach($values as $key=>$row){                     
            $processed_cols = array();

            foreach($row as $key=>$col){                
                if(is_numeric(str_replace(',','',$col))){
                    $col = str_replace(',','',$col);
                }

                if($col[0] == '$'){             
                    $processed_cols[$columns[$key]] = str_replace('$','',$col);                 
                }else{
                    $processed_cols[$columns[$key]] = $col;                 
                }
            }

            $values_by_column_key[] = $processed_cols;
        }                   

        if(!empty($sort_by)){
            usort($values_by_column_key, function($a,$b)use($sort_by,$sort_dir){                                    

                if($sort_dir == 'ASC'){
                    return $a[$sort_by] > $b[$sort_by];                             
                }elseif($sort_dir == 'DESC'){                   
                    return $a[$sort_by] < $b[$sort_by];         
                }                               
            });
        }   

        echo '<table class="data-table">'.PHP_EOL;
            echo '<thead>'.PHP_EOL;
                echo '<tr>'.PHP_EOL;

                    if(!empty($included_cols)){
                        foreach($included_cols as $col){
                            echo '<th>'.$col['label'].'</th>'.PHP_EOL;
                        }
                    }

                echo '</tr>'.PHP_EOL;               
            echo '</thead>'.PHP_EOL;        
            echo '<tbody>'.PHP_EOL;                     

            $row_count = 0;         

            foreach($values_by_column_key as $key1=>$row){
                $row_count++;

                if($row_count <= RESULT_LIMIT){
                    echo '<tr>'.PHP_EOL;

                    foreach($included_cols as $key2=>$inc_cols){
                        if($inc_cols['format'] == 'currency'){
                            echo '<td>'.$inc_cols['currency_symbol'].$row[$key2].'</td>'.PHP_EOL;                                                       
                        }else{                                                  
                            echo '<td>'.$row[$key2].'</td>'.PHP_EOL;
                        }
                    }                                                           

                    echo '</tr>'.PHP_EOL;
                }
            }                       

            echo '</tbody>'.PHP_EOL;                            
        echo '</table>'.PHP_EOL;                
    }
```

**FUNCTION TO READ AND PARSE CSV FILE**

```
function getCampaignsCSVData($account){

        $data = array();

        $dir = ADWORDS_REPORTS_DIR.$account.'/';

        $filename = ADWORDS_CAMPAIGN_FILE;      
        $filepath = $dir.$filename; 

        $row_count = 0;

        if(file_exists($filepath)){         
            $csvfile = @fopen($filepath,'r');

            if($csvfile){                               
                while(!feof($csvfile)){                 
                    $row = fgets($csvfile);

                    $row = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z ]/", "", $row);

                    $row_count++;

                    $row_data = ''; 


                    if(stristr($row,CAMPAIGNS_REPORT_IN_COLUMNS_WORD)){             
                        $row_data = str_replace('Impr.','Impressions',$row);                    
                        $row_data = str_replace('Interactions','Clicks',$row_data);

                        $data['columns'] = str_getcsv($row_data);                                                               
                        $columns_row_index = $row_count;


                    } elseif($row_count > $columns_row_index && !empty($columns_row_index)){
                        $row_data = $row;                       

                        if(!stristr($row,'Total') && !empty($row)){                     
                            $data['values'][] = str_getcsv($row_data);                          
                        }                       
                    }                   
                }
            }           

            fclose($csvfile);
        }else{
            $data = false;
        }           

        return $data;       
    }
```

This code has been working for a long time but it suddenly stopped working recently without changing anything. I can't seem to get my head around it because I can't find any error. Please help. Thanks!

Comment: Can you do a var_dump($data) before your return statement in `getCampaignsCSVData` and let us know if it has data that you are expecting?

Comment: @Dimi var_dump gives me this - array(2) { ["columns"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(186) "Campaign statusCampaignBudget nameCurrency codeBudgetBudget typeStatusOptimization scoreCampaign typeImprClicksInteraction rateAvg costCostConversionsCost convConv rateBid strategy type" } ["values"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(63) "EnabledEV Charger Installation CADDailyEligibleSearchTarget CPA" } } }

Comment: As you cans see, I'm getting the row values but it's coming as a string. It was supposed to be an array.